# Angular hosted in folder but cant access assets

Tags: angular, assets

My Angular project needs to be in a folder for example:

`site.com/folder/#/login`

And I ended up losing access to assets, because I access it like this:

`<img src="/assets/logo.svg" />`

How could I solve it without having to put several slashes like ../../../?

If I use it like this, the build is all disorganized.

Comment: try building your app with `--base-href="/folder/" `  parameter

Comment: I will try, thanks!

Comment: Did not work. Any other ideas? I made the build like this: ng build --configuration="hmg" --deploy-url "/operations-portal-app/" --base-href="/operations-portal-app/"

Comment: For solve this, i use --base-href local too. And in all paths i write the absolute path. So all paths now have the fake subfolder. Example: /folder/assets/img.jpg